# Is there a way to implement grid header with dynamic height using react-virtualized?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm developing a data grid component based on react-virtualized. It's supposed to have a fixed header with resizable columns. I want the header to change its height according to the header cells content. I'm using [CellMeasurer](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md) to calculate cells height and update height of the header.

The problem is that cell sizes are calculated after the cells are rendered (afaik), so I have to call `forceUpdate` inside of the header's `render` if height has been changed.

here is how `render` looks like (complete example is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/88j0vo10k2)):

```
render() {
    const height = this._cache.rowHeight({ index: 0 });
    console.log('render', height, this.props.sizes);
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (height !== this._cache.rowHeight({ index: 0 })) {
        console.log('forceUpdate', this._cache.rowHeight({ index: 0 }))
        this.forceUpdate()
      }
    }, 0)

    return (
      <Grid 
        ref={ref => this._grid = ref}
        deferredMeasurementCache={this._cache}
        width={1500}
        height={height}
        columnCount={5}
        columnWidth={this.columnWidth}
        rowCount={1}
        rowHeight={this._cache.rowHeight}
        cellRenderer={this.renderCell}
      />
    );
  }
```

so the question is how do I avoid `forceUpdate`? Is there a cleaner way to implement grid header with dynamic height using react-virtualized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like I have to post it as an answer.

Brian pointed to the right direction, thanks Brian for your amazing work and support.

That `onSectionRendered` handler is important, because it lets us update header's height after the first render:

```
_onSectionRendered = ({ rowOverscanStartIndex }) => {
    if (rowOverscanStartIndex === 0) {
      const height = this._cache.rowHeight({ index: 0 });

      if (height !== this.state.headerHeight) {
        this.setState({
          headerHeight: height,
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

`componentWillReceiveProps` from the original codesandbox is important as well -- it what makes component react on the columns resizing:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.sizes !== this.props.sizes) {
      this._cache.clearAll();
      console.log('recomputeGridSize');
      this._grid.recomputeGridSize();
      console.log('===', this._cache.rowHeight({ index: 0 }))
    }
  }
```

What was missing is `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate',
      this._cache.rowHeight({ index: 0 }));
    const height = this._cache.rowHeight({ index: 0 });

    if (height !== this.state.headerHeight) {
      this.setState({
        headerHeight: height,
      });
    }
  }
```

-- this is the method where we can check whether the row's height differs from the header's height and update it if necessary. `componentDidUpdate` is not called after initial render, that's why `onSectionRendered` is helpful.

Though it doesn't avoid an extra render, it's much cleaner than timeout hack.
Complete example is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/kor4vv6jqv.

Answer (score 2):

Setting timeouts in `render` is probably not a good idea.

If the height of a cell changes (eg the value returned from `rowHeight`) then [`CellMeasurer` will automatically notify the parent `Grid`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/2b5396f6f0f09c22fb15ff258179e2bf62783bfb/source/CellMeasurer/CellMeasurer.js#L108-L117). In that case, [`Grid` will automatically clear its position cache and re-render](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/2b5396f6f0f09c22fb15ff258179e2bf62783bfb/source/Grid/Grid.js#L1117-L1130).

What you're doing differently in this example is setting the outer height of the `Grid` to be equal to the cell-measured height. This isn't a common use-case, *but* you could support it without the timer-hack like so:

```
class XHeader extends React.Component {
  _cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
    defaultHeight: 20,
    fixedWidth: true,
  });
  state = {
    headerHeight: 20,
  };
  renderCell = props => {
    return (
      <HeaderCell 
        width={this.props.sizes[props.columnIndex]}
        {...props}
        cache={this._cache}
        onMouseDown={this.props.onMouseDown}
      />
    );
  }
  columnWidth = ({ index }) => {
    return this.props.sizes[index];
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid 
        ref={ref => this._grid = ref}
        deferredMeasurementCache={this._cache}
        width={1500}
        height={this.state.headerHeight}
        columnCount={5}
        columnWidth={this.columnWidth}
        onSectionRendered={this._onSectionRendered}
        rowCount={1}
        rowHeight={this._cache.rowHeight}
        cellRenderer={this.renderCell}
      />
    );
  }

  _onSectionRendered = ({ rowOverscanStartIndex }) => {
    if (rowOverscanStartIndex === 0) {
      const height = this._cache.rowHeight({ index: 0 });

      if (height !== this.state.headerHeight) {
        this.setState({
          headerHeight: height,
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Brian, thank you for your support and work you do! As for the answer, this is a bit different from what I tried to achieve, though helped a lot.